# compile colord [docbok2man does not process "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook V4.1//EN"] xml catalog files

Tags: libxml2, docbook, sgml, xmlcatalog

```
  GEN      colormgr.1
  GEN      cd-create-profile.1
  GEN      cd-fix-profile.1
cd-fix-profile.sgml:1: cd-create-profile.sgml:1: colormgr.sgml:1: parser parser error : parser error : error : StartTag: invalid element name
StartTag: invalid element name
StartTag: invalid element name
<!doctype refentry PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook V4.1//EN" [
 ^
<!doctype refentry PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook V4.1//EN" [
<!doctype refentry PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook V4.1//EN" [
 ^
cd-create-profile.sgml:1: cd-fix-profile.sgml:1: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
 ^
parser colormgr.sgml:1: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
<!doctype refentry PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook V4.1//EN" [
 ^
error : <!doctype refentry PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook V4.1//EN" [
 ^
Extra content at the end of the document
unable to parse colormgr.sgml
unable to parse cd-fix-profile.sgml
<!doctype refentry PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook V4.1//EN" [
 ^
unable to parse cd-create-profile.sgml
Unable to recognise encoding of this document at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/XML/SAX/PurePerl/EncodingDetect.pm line 100.
Document requires an element [Ln: 1, Col: 0]
Makefile:634: recipe for target 'cd-fix-profile.1' failed
make[2]: *** [cd-fix-profile.1] Error 255
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I am trying to compile colord, but having a hard time grasping how docbook and xml catalog files are working. Which is where I suspect the problem is, that I don't have an XML_CATALOG_FILES for Docbook SGML v4.1. Not sure how to create a catalog that should point to these schema defintions [http://www.docbook.org/sgml/4.1/].

Comment: XML_CATALOG_FILES is an environment variable. You can find more about how catalogs work [here](http://xmlsoft.org/catalog.html). But usually, it should be enough to install a distro package with the right DTDs.

Comment: Thanks, I should probably go peek at a distro package and see how they are laying out the xml catalog(s).

Comment: The public identifier `-//OASIS//DTD DocBook V4.1//EN` indicates that the man page is an SGML document (not XML). It might help if the `--sgml` option is passed to docbook2man (see http://docbook2x.sourceforge.net/latest/doc/docbook2man.html).